# How to compare array of characters to Boolean

Tags: java, arrays, char

I'm not quite sure why this piece of code involving array of characters makes sense?

```
String str1 = "Hello"
int[] charSet = new int[128];
char[] chars = str1.toCharArray();
    for (char c : chars) { // count number of each char in s.
        if (charSet[c] == 0)++charSet[c];
    }
```

My Question is how is it you can char variable as an index for the charSet array and compare it to 0?

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Comment: Zero is an integer, not a boolean

Comment: What statement do you expect to see an error in and what error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `char` is an unsigned 16-bit numeric type, and will be widened to `int` when used as an array index.

`charSet[c]` is implicitly `charSet[(int) c]`

Note that the code will fail if non-ASCII characters are in the string, because only [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) characters are in Unicode code point range 0-127. Any other Unicode character will cause `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Answer (score 1):

the code with my comments.

```
    String str1 = "Hello";
    int[] charSet = new int[128];// ascii chars a-z and A-Z go from 65-122 using a 128 array is just being lazy
    char[] chars = str1.toCharArray();
    for (char c : chars) { //loop though each character in the string
        if (charSet[c] == 0)//c is the character converted to int since it's all a-z A-Z it's between 65 and 122                                
            ++charSet[c];//if it the character hasn't been seen before set to 1
    }
```